# DotNetNuke Catalook Store error while creating orders

Tags: dotnetnuke, store

I am having issues with the Catalook checkout erroring out when creating orders and I'm having a hard time finding good information about the store and common issues/answers. The error that I am getting is a null reference in the AssignSerialNumbers() method. The site uses DNN v7.4.1 and the catalook store version is 7.1.2. I inherited this DNN project and am still getting used to all of the options and settings in DNN. [error screenshot with full stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbIn.png)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get to the bottom of this issue. The null reference in AssignSerialNumbers() was not the root issue. I found that the previous developer had capped the auto-growth of the database file and it had run out of space. Ouch.